# build with opencv4.3.0 has an inline error in cvstd_wrapper file

Tags: c++, opencv, c++14

I'm building openpilot with opencv4.3.0,

and there's an error in opencv header file:

```
clang++ -o selfdrive/camerad/cameras/camera_webcam.o -c -std=c++14 -DWEBCAM -g -fPIC -O2 -Wunused -Werror -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-inconsistent-missing-override -Iexternal/tensorflow/include -I. -Iselfdrive -Iphonelibs/bzip2 -Iphonelibs/libyuv/include -Iphonelibs/openmax/include -Iphonelibs/json11 -Iphonelibs/curl/include -Iphonelibs/libgralloc/include -Iphonelibs/android_frameworks_native/include -Iphonelibs/android_hardware_libhardware/include -Iphonelibs/android_system_core/include -Iphonelibs/linux/include -Iphonelibs/snpe/include -Iphonelibs/nanovg -Iselfdrive/common -Iselfdrive/camerad -Iselfdrive/camerad/include -Iselfdrive/loggerd/include -Iselfdrive/modeld -Iselfdrive/sensord -Iselfdrive/ui -Icereal/messaging -Icereal -Iopendbc/can -Iphonelibs/json11 -I/usr/local/include/opencv4 selfdrive/camerad/cameras/camera_webcam.cc
In file included from selfdrive/camerad/cameras/camera_webcam.cc:13:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core.hpp:54:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/base.hpp:58:
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd.hpp:81:
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:47:60: error: inline function
      'cv::sfinae::has_parenthesis_operator<cv::DefaultDeleter<cv::detail::PaniniPortraitWarper>, void, cv::detail::PaniniPortraitWarper
      *>::check<cv::DefaultDeleter<cv::detail::PaniniPortraitWarper> >' is not defined [-Werror,-Wundefined-inline]
    template<typename> static CV_CONSTEXPR std::false_type check(...);
                                                           ^
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:49:22: note: used here
    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;
                     ^
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:47:60: error: inline function 'cv::sfinae::has_parenthesis_operator<cv::DefaultDeleter<cv::detail::FisheyeWarper>,
      void, cv::detail::FisheyeWarper *>::check<cv::DefaultDeleter<cv::detail::FisheyeWarper> >' is not defined [-Werror,-Wundefined-inline]
    template<typename> static CV_CONSTEXPR std::false_type check(...);
                                                           ^
/usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/core/cvstd_wrapper.hpp:49:22: note: used here
    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;
                     ^
```

any suggestions?

Thanks.

I build the opencv with c++11 so I changed cxxflag from -std=c++14 to -std=c++11, but it comes with the same error.

the content of opencv header file:

```
namespace sfinae {
template<typename C, typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct has_parenthesis_operator
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    static CV_CONSTEXPR std::true_type check(typename std::is_same<typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>().operator()(std::declval<Args>()...))>::type, Ret>::type*);

    template<typename> static CV_CONSTEXPR std::false_type check(...);

    typedef decltype(check<C>(0)) type;

public:
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L || (defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1900/*MSVS 2015*/)
    static CV_CONSTEXPR bool value = type::value;
#else
    // support MSVS 2013
    static const int value = type::value;
#endif
};
} // namespace sfinae
```